# setInterval() ajax call is working on local server but giving error in online server

Tags: ajax

I have a website in which there is chatroom where I use to send AJAX request to check if a person received a new message or not. If a new message is received, it gets appended to the DOM without refreshing the page (like Facebook).

I am using:-

```
setInterval(check_if_new_message, 1000);
```

i.e. one AJAX request to check message every one second.

This was working fine as it was supposed to when I was trying to run on the local server. But then I bought Starter Shared Linux Hosting on GoDaddy and then my ajax requests are not working properly. First 100-150 requests are working fine but after that, it stars giving an error like **`net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`** in the console of the browser.

```
setInterval(check_if_new_message, 1000);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP or MySQL?

Comment: check your server logs; there is not enough information on this question to begin even 'guess' at the issue is.  do you get a JS error? it sounds like you are hitting some kind of API limit but there is no additional info.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and add more code/additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that you are using:

```
setInterval(check_if_new_message, 1000);
```

That means you are calling **check_if_new_message** after every 1 second. This works well in the localhost because it is on your computer. But when you try this on a live server, you will get:

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

This is because your server can not handle so many requests. Your server may have less RAM.

This is not a good practice for a real-time chat application.

If you want to make a realtime chat application use **WebSocket** for that.

Useful resources for WebSocket:

[What is WebSocket?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-web-socket-and-how-it-is-different-from-the-http/)

[WS library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)