# Multiple AJAX request in localhost is working but making my live server down

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am making an application where I need to check the database if new data is available to show. For that in JQuery I am doing:

```
    function check_new_data(){
    $.post("./get_new_data",{},function(e){
    if(e!=""){
    //do something
    }
    });
    }

    var interval = 0
    setInterval(check_new_data(), interval);
```

This is working good in localhost server but when I upload my site to the live server it crashes my site and makes site unreachable for sometime.

Comment: Most likely that `interval = 0` is causing the browser to send "infinite" requests to your server, causing a DOS style attack on yourself. You really need to put an actual delay in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `interval = 0`. That means infinite requests. This will not harm your localhost but can harm your live server.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63604449/11910869

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the full url path from which you are fetching the data.

```
function check_new_data(){
$.post("http://example.com/get_new_data",{},function(e){
if(e!=""){
}
});
}
var interval = 0
setInterval(check_new_data(), interval);
```